# Generate `avsc` files from `avdl` with pure JS

Tags: javascript, avro

I know that it's possible to transform `avdl` to series of `avsc` files using java tools provided by Apache.

But despite the website lists plenty of implementations on different languages too, including JS, it seems to be that there is no support for `avdl -> avsc` conversion in these.

What would be your recommendation how to perform this conversion in pure JavaScript? Does such library even exists or we're forced to go through pure Java implementation always?

Answer (score 1):

Java seems to be the only language that they implemented the compilation from avdl to avsc. The easiest route is probably just to have the `avro-tools.jar` somewhere and then have your JS code call out to that in some sub process to compile the schemas.

The other option would be to re-implement the IDL compiler in JS. I wouldn't do that, but the Java implementation is pretty much all contained within https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/compiler/src/main/javacc/org/apache/avro/compiler/idl/idl.jj if you wanted to take a look.